# What does this formula state?

Tags: graph-theory, relations, predicate-logic

I have the following formula in predicate logic:

∀x∀y∃z(R(x, z) ∧ ¬R(y, z))

I am not entirely sure what it states as for me it states a contradiction.
Asuming it is a graph and Relation R(x,y) means that x is adjacent to y, this formula says that for all nodes in the graph they are adjacent to z and they aren't adjacent to z, or do I have it wrong and one should make the distinguishment between x and y, meaning that for a some nodes x in the graph they are adjacent to z and for other nodes y they aren't adjacent to z?

Thank youu:)

Comment: What is the context in which you found this formula?

Comment: It does lead to an inconsistency by choosing $y=x$, because it asserts the existence of $z$ such that both $R(x,z)$ and $\lnot R(x,z)$ (contradiction).  But I'm not sure if that answers your Question.

Comment: the context is to decide whether the following formula is satisfiable with an infinite/finite Model: Φ4 := {∀x∀y∃z(R(x, z) ∧ ¬R(y, z)), ∃a∀b(R(b, a) ∨ a = b), ∀x∀y(R(x, y) → g(x) = y)}

Comment: Ok, in that case the first formula (the one in the post) is never satisfied any model (unless there are no elements).

Comment: thanks a lot but wouldn't it still be unsatisfiable even when there are no elements because in that case there still exists no z that is in relation to x and not to y as the graph is empty hence still never true?

Answer (score 3):

The formula states that for any $x$ and $y$ there is a $z$ that is related to $x$ but not $y$. Since the quantifiers $\forall x\forall y$ do not necessarily imply $x\neq y$, you are correct that this formula can never be true. In order to obtain a formula that could be true, there needs to be an assumption that $x\neq y$. Something like:
$$
\forall x\forall y  (x\neq y\rightarrow \exists z(R(x,z) \wedge \neg R(y,z)))
$$

Answer (score 0):

Generally
$$(A \land \neg B) = \neg(\neg A \lor B)= \neg (A \Rightarrow B)$$
So you have
$$\forall x \forall y \exists z \left( \neg(R(x,z) \Rightarrow R(y,z)) \right)$$

Comment: which can also never be true right?

Comment: seems so, because in implication there is same first and second members, so implication is always true and its negation is always false.